# How do I disable the "Add to cart" button when a user has already a product in the cart?

Tags: nodes, ubercart

I need to sell a node on my website and I'm using the *Ubercart* and *Paypal Express Checkout* modules. It works: I can buy a node by clicking on the *Add to cart* button on the product page and *Checkout with Paypal* in the shopping cart page.
I grant a role when the product has bought.
Now, when I return to the product page, I see again the *Add to cart* button, even if I bought the node.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: That's the default behavior. You want all nodes to only be available for purchase one time? Or just one specific node for that specific customer who has purchased that specific node? A little more detail in the question might help.

Comment: Hi, I want the node purchased one time by customer. If customer has already bought the node, he can see it forever.